# File download gets slower after first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

The first time this method is invoked the file is downloaded instantly, however it is taking longer and longer each time a file is requested for download. I am not sure why.

I am using the DocX library to replace string in a word document, and then save this file.

After saving, I read the file and download as below:

```
public void Download(int){

var model = new ApplicantNotificationViewModel();
var fileName = "";
var filePath = "";                

//business address
var businessAddressModel = (from aps in db.AppSettings
                            select new {
                            BusinessAddress1 = aps.BusinessAddress1,
                            BusinessAddress2 = aps.BusinessAddress2,
                            BusinessAddress3 = aps.BusinessAddress3
                            }).FirstOrDefault();

            // Load a .docx file
            using (DocX document = DocX.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\files\\template.docx"))
            {
                /*
                 * Replace each instance of the string pear with the string banana.
                 * Specifying true as the third argument informs DocX to track the
                 * changes made by this replace. The fourth argument tells DocX to
                 * ignore case when matching the string pear.
                 * document.ReplaceText("pear", banana, true, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);*/

                //business address
                document.ReplaceText("BusinessAddress1", businessAddressModel.BusinessAddress1, false, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                document.ReplaceText("BusinessAddress2", businessAddressModel.BusinessAddress2, false, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                document.ReplaceText("BusinessAddress3", businessAddressModel.BusinessAddress3, false, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            string fileSavePath = "SomePath";
                // Save changes made to this document
                fileName = "foo";
                filePath = fileSavePath + fileName + ".docx";
                document.SaveAs(filePath);
            }// Release this document from memory.

        //open saved doc
        using (var fs = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            //open saved doc
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                fs.CopyTo(ms);
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                  "attachment;" + "filename=" + fileName + ".docx");
                Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0,
                     ms.GetBuffer().Length);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
}
```

**Update:**

Having broken down the code, it appears that the request is taking a long time to reach the mvc controller after the first file download

IIS Log

```
2017-06-13 21:42:45 ::1 GET / 200 0 0 94
2017-06-13 21:43:55 ::1 GET /Applicant/Download applicantid=1&templateid=1 
2017-06-13 21:44:19 ::1 GET /Applicant/Download applicantid=11&templateid=2 
2017-06-13 21:45:13 ::1 GET /Applicant/Download applicantid=11&templateid=2
```

Comment: before calling the `Response.AddHeader()` method, try adding the following to see if it makes a difference `Response.Clear();` look into `Response.End() and Response.Close()` methods as well

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have tried Response.Clear() and Response.ClearContent() but still same issue. When a page refresh takes around 14 seconds after first file download

Comment: perhaps you are not closing / ending the response properly

Comment: You need to add a Response.End() after the write.

Comment: Tried that also, didn't work. In the below answer, raises a good point about document generation. I will update the OP

Comment: Maybe try checking if the file you're trying to save already exists. If it already exists, delete it first and then save the new file.

Comment: it doesn't exist, for the purposes of this example I have named it "foo", however I append the datetime to the filename so each time it is a new file so to speak

Comment: Try doing this in a console application (in a while exit == false loop) to see if it's asp.net related or not.

Comment: After first download, the request takes around 10secs to reach the controller, then the file generation is fine.

Comment: Does the problem happen when you use a second browser to access the subsequent document instead of the same browser?

Comment: Okay so I fixed the issue, thanks for the comments and suggestion guys. Basically because first file is loaded using the DocX library after the using statement ends, it is still in use and not disposed off in memory. I have also changed the method DocX.Load() to use the second overload which takes in a Stream Object(point taken from Steven Lemmens) . The file was also being saved in the solution bin folder, I changed the path to another destination, https://forums.iis.net/t/1209378.aspx based on this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I fixed the issue, thanks for the comments and suggestion guys. Basically because first file is loaded using the DocX library after the using statement ends, it is still in use and not disposed off in memory. I have also changed the method DocX.Load() to use the second overload which takes in a Stream Object(point taken from Steven Lemmens) . The file was also being saved in the solution bin folder, I changed the path to another destination, forums.iis.net/t/1209378.aspx based on this link

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a using-statement around your `FileStream` as well, like this:

```
public void DownloadFile()
{
    using (var fs = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open)) {
         //open saved doc
         using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
         {
            fs.CopyTo(ms);
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
              "attachment;" + "filename=" + fileName + ".docx");
            Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, 
                 ms.GetBuffer().Length);
            ms.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

This will ensure the Filestream is closed correctly

Comment: Tried this just now, and still same result

Comment: Are you sure that the generation of the file isn't getting slower and slower in that case?

Comment: Good point, let me post the full code. How can I even track the generation?